# DataTable with ajax via route not showing data laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, datatable

this is the code im using to fill my datatable, but no data is printed,
this is the route i create to access data, i can see it when i acces directly with the web:

```
Route::get('listsolicitudes/solicitudes','Admin\ListrequestController@getTable')->name('datatable.solicitudes');
```

And this is the script I am using:

```
$(function() {
    $('#tablesolicitud').DataTable({
        "ajax":{
            "url": "{{route('datatable.solicitudes')}}",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },      
        "columns": [
            { "data": "order_id" },
            { "data": "request_date" },
            { "data": "status_order_id" },
            { "data": "user_name" },
            { "data": "type" },
            { "data": "cause" },
            { "data": "detail_cause" }                    
            ],
    });
});
```

As someone requested, this  is the controller:

```
public function getTable(){
    $solicitudes = Workshoporder::select('order_id','request_date','status_order_id','user_name','type','cause','detail_cause')->get();

    return datatables()->of($solicitudes)->toJson();

}
```

Comment: Post your controller code `Admin\ListrequestController@getTable`

Comment: I have just update with the controller code